# Parsing/Looping over JSON objects from a text file (Python)

Tags: python, json

simple question. I have a text file containing JSON objects which hold real estate information, like so:

```
     {
      "marketing_package_url": "http://www.capitalpacific.com/inquiry/TrailsEndMarketplaceExecSummary.pdf",
     "title": "TRAILS END MARKETPLACE",
      "location": "OREGON CITY, OR"
      }
```

In my script, I have a list of marketing package URLS.  I want to cross-check the URLS from that list with the URL's in the json objects in this text file so I can find the 'new' URLS.  Any suggestions? I was thinking along the lines of importing the json objects into a separate list, and then using the URL's from that list.

```
import json
with open('properties.txt', 'r') as filename:
           data = json.loads('properties.txt')
```

how to split it up and send URLS to a list?

Comment: Can you show what `data` looks like?  `import pprint; pprint.pprint(data)` would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to get the list of marketing_package_urls to list, if the data is a list of dictionaries.

```
list = [x['marketing_package_url'] for x in data]
```