# pythonic way of iterating over a collection of json objects stored in a text file

Tags: python, json

I have a text file that has several thousand json objects (meaning the textual representation of json) one after the other. They're not separated and I would prefer not to modify the source file. How can I load/parse each json in python? (I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893105/parsing-looping-over-json-objects-from-a-text-file-python), but if I'm not mistaken, this only works for a list of jsons (alreay separated by a comma?) My file looks like this:

```
{"json":1}{"json":2}{"json":3}{"json":4}{"json":5}...
```

Comment: Are they single dimension or do you have nested json objects too?

Comment: What you ahve is not JSON but a JSON like file.

Comment: How have you ended up in this situation? Can you change the code that's creating this file? Unlike e.g. `pickle`, `json` won't load consecutive objects from a file separately.

Comment: Json multimple object are stored in a json array, something like this [{"json":4}, {"json":5}] what you have is kind of a diferente thing

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Does it matter? That's what I have. The question is, is there a clean way to split the jsons in a pythonic way, programmatically, without resorting to changing the source file itself? I'm asking for nice way to do it, not whether what I have is nice or not. I can always use sed to split the files, or python.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, of course, it doesn't; but having a file that's full of almost-but-not-quite-JSON seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, and there may be a way to solve a slightly different problem that makes this one go away.

Comment: You also haven't provided us any code. You just plopped some JSON-like text here and are asking for *teh codez plz* to get it parsed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The json objects are well-formed in the file. The only problem I have is that there is more than one *well-formed* json object per file!

Comment: Yes, but my point is that there are various steps of the process at which this problem could be solved. If there is a good reason (i.e. beyond *"prefer not to"*) that you *need* to parse this file, then please explain what it is. As @IanAuld points out, some evidence of an attempt to implement this yourself would also be appreciated.

Comment: If you have your JSON objects as a JSON array in the file, you can just do `json.load`, not?

Comment: @Gx1sptDTDa the whole point of this question is that *they aren't a JSON array*...

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I could split the file like `csplit foo.jsons '\}\{'` and that would work(although I end up with a thousand little files), I would like a pythonic way to do it programmatically without touching the input file, that's all. If there is no easy way or nobody knows of one, that's fine. I can do a bunch of other Linux-y things on the file.

Comment: This is actually pretty trivial to do with Python, provided you have no nested JSON objects.

Comment: @jonrsharpe then just the text split it on whatever the delimiter is, and iteratively load in in the resulting blobs with `json.loads`.

Comment: @DervinThunk Have you taken a look at my answer below? i am wondering if it works for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a clean way to do this without using the real JSON parser.  The other options of modifying the text and using a non-JSON parser are risky.  So the best way to go it find a way to iterate using the real JSON parser so that you're sure to comply with the JSON spec.

The core idea is to let the real JSON parser do all the work in identifying the groups:

```
import json, re

combined = '{"json":1}{"json":2}{"json":3}{"json":4}{"json":5}'

start = 0
while start != len(combined):
    try:
        json.loads(combined[start:])
    except ValueError as e:
        pass
    # Find the location where the parsing failed
    end = start + int(re.search(r'column (\d+)', e.args[0]).group(1)) - 1
    result = json.loads(combined[start:end])
    start = end
    print(result)
```

This outputs:

```
{u'json': 1}
{u'json': 2}
{u'json': 3}
{u'json': 4}
{u'json': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following would work as long as there are no non-comma-delimited json arrays of json sub-objects inside any of the outermost json objects. It's somewhat brute-force in that it reads the whole file into memory and attempts to fix it.

```
import json

def get_json_array(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rt') as jsonfile:
        json_array = '[{}]'.format(jsonfile.read().replace('}{', '},{'))
        return json.loads(json_array)

for obj in get_json_array('multiobj.json'):
    print(obj)
```

Output:

```
{u'json': 1}
{u'json': 2}
{u'json': 3}
{u'json': 4}
{u'json': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the source file, just make a copy. Use a regex to replace `}{` with `},{` and then hopefully a pre-built json reader will take care of it nicely.

EDIT: quick solution:

```
from re import sub

with open(inputfile, 'r') as fin:
    text = sub(r'}{', r'},{', fin.read())
with open(outfile, 'w' as fout:
    fout.write('[')
    fout.write(text)
    fout.write(']')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = '{"json":1}{"json":2}{"json":3}{"json":4}{"json":5}'
>>> [ast.literal_eval(ele + '}') for ele in s.split('}')[:-1]]
[{'json': 1}, {'json': 2}, {'json': 3}, {'json': 4}, {'json': 5}]
```

Provided you have no nested objects and splitting on `'}'` is feasible this can be accomplished pretty simply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one pythonic way to do it:

```
from json.scanner import make_scanner
from json import JSONDecoder

def load_jsons(multi_json_str):
    s = multi_json_str.strip()
    scanner = make_scanner(JSONDecoder())
    idx = 0
    objects = []
    while idx < len(s):
       obj, idx = scanner(s, idx)
       objects.append(obj)
    return objects
```

I think `json` was never supposed to be used this way, but it solves your problem.

I agree with @Raymond Hettinger, you need to use `json` itself to do the work, text manipulation doesn't work for complex JSON objects. His answer parses the exception message to find the split position. It works, but it looks like a hack, hence, not pythonic :)

EDIT:
Just found out this is actually supported by `json` module, just use `raw_decode` like this:

```
decoder = JSONDecoder()
first_obj, remaining = decoder.raw_decode(multi_json_str)
```

Read http://pymotw.com/2/json/index.html#mixed-data-streams